# How to fix reduce Method returning nothing (Laravel)

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, reduce

I want to iterate through $student collection and multiply each value from `$defaultValue` and check whether it's less than or equal to the number I am getting from json data `$jsonData->value`. if any is less than `$jsonData->value`, will return true. But it is not returning anything ! why is that ? i have checked the code and found that, when i print `$carry` its not assigned as false. (according to this the default value of $carry is false). how to fix it ?

```
$jsonData = json_decode($request->data);

if ($jsonData->value!==0){
   foreach ($array as $key => $data){
      $lectures = Lecture::where('hall_id','=',$data['id'])->get();
           foreach ($lectures as $lecture){
              $student = Student::where('lecture_id','=',$lecture->id)
                   ->where('date','>=',$jsonData->dateOne)
                   ->where('date','<=',$jsonData->dateTwo)
                   ->get();

              $defaultValue = $lecture->value;

              if (!$student ->isEmpty()){

                   $multiplied = collect($student )
                      ->reduce(function($carry, $item) use ($defaultValue ,$jsonData){
                           return $carry || $item->number * $defaultValue <=$jsonData->value;
                   }, false);

          }

    }
}
```

$student returns

```
[{"id":2,"number ":10},{"id":79,"number ":1},{"id":9,"number ":4}]
```

$defaultValue reurns

```
2
```

$jsonData->value returns

```
10
```

Comment: Have you tried `function($carry, $item) use ($defaultValue)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$carry || (($item->number * $defaultValue) <=$jsonData->value);
```

Comment: i tried it but still has the same error. not returning anything